# Issue iterating through ArrayLists

Tags: java, foreach, arraylist

I have two questions. I have an object here that is of type `ArrayList`, and for this case let's call it `"Car"`.

I have made 2 of them:

```
Car car1 = new Car();
Car car2 = new Car();
```

I have a function to add items to those Car objects:

```
car1.addPart("Front Wheels");
car1.addPart("Rear Wheels");
car1.addPart("Rear View Mirror");

car2.addPart("Rims");
car2.addPart("Steering Wheel");
car2.addPart("Bumper");
```

---

I need to have a function called `sameContents()` that I can call on `car1`:

```
car1.sameContents(car2);
```

which passes in an object of type `ArrayList` and checks it with `car1` to see if they have the same contents and in the same order.

```
public boolean sameContents(Car c) {
    ArrayList<String> other_car = c; // error: Type mismatch: 
                                    // cannot convert from Car to ArrayList<String>

    for (String c : this.parts) {
        System.out.println(c);
        for(String oc : other_car) { 
             // stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I seem to be having all sorts of issues with this one. I can't get the `other_car` variable to be used in a foreach loop.

---

The second one that needs to be done is `transferContents`.

It's called like:

```
car1.transferContents(car2);
```

which transfers the items in `car2` into `car1` and then leaves `car2` empty. I can't seem to get the `ArrayList` to work again in a foreach loop which is what I think I need.

```
 public void transfer(Car c) {
     // code for transfer method.
     // this.parts is the arraylist of car parts
     for (Car c: c) {
    this.parts.add(c);
      }
    // not sure how to set car2 to empty...
 }
```

Comment: Ok... and... what is your question? What do you have so far? What have you tried?

Comment: Agree with Oscar (1+). We're not going to do your code for you as this isn't a "do my homework for me service". So show us what you've tried and tell us how it's not working.

Comment: @oscarRyz I need help writing the transfer and sameContents methods. I've tried nesting foreach loops but I can't use the arguments 'c' and 'other_car' as arraylists or arrays when trying to do the loop. so I am uncertain of how to do it

Comment: @Drew: "I need help" doesn't cut it. Again, ***show us*** what you've tried -- as in *code*.

Comment: check the edit on sameContents... i'll add in transfer in a second

Comment: Does Car extend ArrayList? Or does it *contain* an ArrayList?

Comment: Also, if you haven't done so, you may wish to have Car implement Iterable<Car> so that you can use it in a foreach loop.

Comment: What error are you getting from 'sameContents' method exact stack trace. If it it nullpointer exception then also show us how is the paramter C populated before it gets passed in. Why are you looping 'this.parts'.

Comment: @shahzeb i am getting an error now on the first line of sameContents saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Car to ArrayList<String>"

Comment: Okay thats because other_car has 'Car' objects not 'String' objects in it.Change 'for(String oc : other_car)' to 'for(Car oc : other_car)'

Comment: You still have not answered my questions: does Car extend ArrayList or does it contain an ArrayList, and does it implement Iterable<Car>?

Comment: @Shahzeb: makes no sense "other_car has 'Car' objects not String..." we still have no idea what a Car class is, what it extends, or what it contains.

Comment: OK, never mind, going to bed. Good night and good luck.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Yes I agree. Drew, your question has potential to be very yummy; that's part of the reason why so many of us are here :) but like Hover said we need the complete picture. First I thought your car object has the array, but reading it again, I found you said it is the array. Please add the whole car class here. Is it extending ArrayList?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. I figured out my only issue, it was that i was accessing the arraylist wrong :( I figured it out though. thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Given some `List<T> foo`, foreach loops, e.g.:

```
for(T item : foo){
    // body
}
```

are just a shorthand syntax for this idiom:

```
Iterator<T> iter = foo.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    T item = iter.next();
    // body
}
```

To check that there are more items in the list, you call `iter.hasNext()`, to retrieve the next item, you call `iter.next()`.

Walking two lists can be done by keeping around 2 iterators, checking that both iterators have more elements, and then retrieving those elements. We can eliminate some boundary conditions on different length lists by realizing that different length lists cannot contain the same elements (since one list has more than the other).

From your description, it sounds like `Car` contains a property `List<String> parts;`, so we can formulate a solution as:

```
// different sizes, can't be equal
if(this.parts.size() != other.parts.size()){
    return false;
}

// get iterators
Iterator<String> left = this.parts.iterator();
Iterator<String> right = other.parts.iterator();

// safe to only check `left` because the lists are the same size
while(left.hasNext()){
    // check if left part is equal to the right part
    if(!left.next().equals(right.next())){
        // values are different, know at this
        // point they're not equal
        return false;
    }
}

// at this point, have exactly the same values
// in the same order.
return true;
```

---

As for your `transferContents` method, you have the right idea, but you cannot iterate over the `Car`, you need to iterate over the `List<String> parts`. To remove individual parts, you can use `remove()` method, called like the `add` method, or to remove all elements, you can call `clear()`

Putting this together:

```
for (String part : c.parts) {
    this.parts.add(part);
}
c.parts.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the java api to do all that you need.
The ArrayList equals method checks for order while comparing two lists.
You can use the removeAll() and addAll() methods to transfer contents.

```
public class Car {

    private final List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addPart(String p) {
        parts.add(p);
    }

    public boolean sameContents(Car c) {
        return this.parts.equals(c.parts);
    }

    public void transfer(Car c) {
        final List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(c.parts);
        temp.removeAll(this.parts);
        this.parts.addAll(temp);
        c.parts.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your car should not **be** an array list, but **have** one. E.g. something like this:

```
class Car {
    ArrayList<String> parts;
    // ...
}
```

Then your `sameContents` method can simply call the lists's `.equals()` method to do the comparison:

```
public boolean sameParts(Car other) {
     return this.parts.equals(other.parts);
}
```

Similarly, for transferring parts from another car, use the methods of the Lists to `add` the parts to your list, and then `clear` the other list.